# Proj of some ring.

Tags: combinatorics, geometry, algebraic-geometry, commutative-algebra

Let $R= \mathbb C[x_1,x_2,x_3,x_4,x_5,y_1,y_2,y_3,y_4,y_5]$ be the polynomial ring and let $S$ be the subalgebra generated by $x_1x_2x_3x_4x_5, x_1x_2x_3x_4y_5, \cdots ,y_1y_2y_3y_4y_5$ (the generating set contains all products of x_i's and y_i's with different indices). Then what is Proj (S) ? My guess is it is $(\mathbb P^1)^5$ but I don't know how to prove this.

Comment: This should have dimension 10, since the ring has dimension 10 if we invert the variables. That said, I believe this is just $\mathbb{P}^{10}$. We have an embedding $\mathbb{P}^{10}\to \mathbb{P}^{2^5}$ given by taking the generators of the subalgebra, and this is an isomorphism onto the image. The proof that this corrosponds to the desired subset follows from an aurgument similar to that of the Veronese mapping.

Comment: The transcendence degree is 6, so the projective variety is of dimension 5 not 10.